# Keeping CodeIgniter session active

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter app and some plain PHP stuff on a domain e.g. I visit my CodeIgniter app at http://foo.com and plain php files at http://foo.com/plainphp/somefile.php

I want to keep the CI session active when I am working at somefile.php for a long period. I kind of understand that something should ping the CI app regularly or even simpler method would be that this ping happens when I refresh somefile.php manually.

My question is:

- What do I need to include in the somefile.php so that the CI session doesn't time out??

Comment: you can set the expiration on the session to a higher value in your config file for starters.

Comment: Does you work with `somefile.php` generate page loads? Maybe you could use the same session handler in both CI and there.

Answer (score 2):

set your session preferences setting in `application/config/config.php`

sess_expiration :The number of seconds you would like the session to last. The default value is 2 hours (7200 seconds). If you would like a non-expiring session set the value to zero: 0

see the documentation of codeigniter : [session settings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)